# Where can I find a list of all the global functions that come with Swift?

Tags: swift

Where can I find a list of all the global functions that come with Swift?

Comment: functions are namespaced to each module that defines them. You don't have to worry about clashing with other global functions

Answer (score 2):

Not a very good solution - but one way is to Command-click on one of the built in types in your source (eg Int) to take you to the declaration.  The whole framework seems to be declared in one large file.

Comment: Thanks, still useful to know.

Comment: or type `import Swift` and command-click on "Swift". it's not a real file

Comment: Thanks!  Just what I was looking for, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If you launch the Swift REPL with the `-integrated-repl` option, and then enter `:print_module Swift` you'll get the "pseudo header" version of all the functions defined in the `Swift` module.

As a shortcut you can just enter `echo :print_module Swift | xcrun swift -integrated-repl` on the command line and it will splat out the list for you.

If the above command fails with an error like ***xcrun: error: unable to find utility "swift", not a developer tool or in PATH*** use `xcode-select` to pick the beta version of Xcode like so: `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer`.

Comment: Thank you - I issue the echo command and got this: "xcrun: error: unable to find utility "swift", not a developer tool or in PATH"

Comment: Try running `/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift`

Comment: @Boon ah, you may have to explicitly select the beta version of Xcode using `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer`

Comment: This does not work with Swift 4 REPL.